# What could be causing a leak on the supply side of a washing machine hose

Tags: plumbing, leak, washing-machine

I have recently installed a new washing machine. In the new machine, as well as for the old one, there is a leak as indicated in the following picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z057M.jpg

What could cause this? I have screwed the clamp tightly by hand - should I be using a tool to do this?

Note: this is on the cold side, and the hoses are new, but the faucets old.

Comment: Looks like the rubber / fibre washer is missing

Comment: Either a missing seal washer as @SiHa says, or a damaged sealing surface on the faucet (a picture of the business end of the faucet with the hose removed might be helpful.)

Comment: hotglue the seat if you can't get a washer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is a washer in there. Compare it to the hot water side for the washer.

These fittings always say "hand tighten ". I have seen very few that tighten sufficiently by hand, especially when dealing with head pressure. Take your pliers or Channelocks and give the nut an eighth of a turn further than your "hand tight".

Comment: Hand tighten+ solved the problem - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There should be a rubber "rubber" washer in the plastic union that screws onto the tap.

(the washer is usually some sort of flexible plastic, not actual rubber)

It's called a hose union washer and should be available at most places that sell hardware or plumbing supplies.

I have in the past used slices of actual rubber hose to replace lost washers.

If there is a piece of fibre in the joint that could cause a slow leak. so when you undo the union to check for the washer, if you do find a washer make sure that it and the surface below it are clean and undamaged, and that the mating face of the tap is also clean.

Comment: A little Teflon tape on the threads wont hurt either